# Matlab GUI reuse function block

Tags: function, matlab, matlab-guide

I have made a Matlab GUI in GUIDE with two editable text boxes and four static text boxes
The user inputs values in the two editable text boxes (`e1` and `e2`) and based on these values it calculates the values that should be displayed in the static text boxes (`s1`, `s2`, `s3` and `s4`).

It does this on each value change of `e1` and `e2`

The code to calculate the values when `e1` changes value is shown below.

```
% --- Executes on key press with focus on e1 and none of its controls.
function e1_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to e1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UICONTROL)
%   Key: name of the key that was pressed, in lower case
%   Character: character interpretation of the key(s) that was pressed
%   Modifier: name(s) of the modifier key(s) (i.e., control, shift) pressed
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Start of BLOCK
% Get values from e1 and e2 and calculate other values
handles.levels = str2num(get(handles.e1, 'String'));
handles.edgelength = str2num(get(handles.e2, 'String'));
handles.cellnum = (handles.levels^3 + 3*handles.levels^2 + 2*handles.levels)/6;
handles.vertnum = ((handles.levels+1)^3 + 3*(handles.levels+1)^2 + 2*(handles.levels+1))/6;

% Set values of s1, s2, s3 and s4
set(handles.s1, 'String', num2str(handles.cellnum));
set(handles.s2, 'String', num2str(handles.vertnum));
set(handles.s3, 'String', num2str(0.433*handles.edgelength^2));
set(handles.s4, 'String', ...
    num2str(2*handles.cellnum*str2num(get(handles.s3, 'String'))));
% End of BLOCK
```

Is it possible to reference this block of code (enclosed in BLOCK) such that `function e2_KeyPressFcn` can use it as well? 
Now I would just copy paste the section to `function e2_KeyPressFcn` but this seems not very elegant.

Comment: Why don't you just put all the code in your new function, and call the function when e1 or e2 changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making a helper function for your block of code?

I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
function e1_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    handles = helper_block_func(handles);

function e2_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    handles = helper_block_func(handles);

function hout = helper_block_func(hin)
    hout = hin;

    % # Get values from e1 and e2 and calculate other values
    hout.levels = str2num(get(hout.e1, 'String'));
    hout.edgelength = str2num(get(hout.e2, 'String'));
    hout.cellnum = (hout.levels ^ 3 + 3 * hout.levels ^ 2 + 2 * hout.levels) / 6;
    hout.vertnum = ((hout.levels + 1) ^ 3 + 3 * (hout.levels + 1) ^ 2 ...
        + 2 * (hout.levels + 1)) / 6

    % # Set values of s1, s2, s3 and s4
    set(hout.s1, 'String', num2str(hout.cellnum));
    set(hout.s2, 'String', num2str(hout.vertnum));
    set(hout.s3, 'String', num2str(0.433 * hout.edgelength ^ 2));
    set(hout.s4, 'String', ...
        num2str(2 * hout.cellnum * str2num(get(hout.s3, 'String'))));
```

Comment: Could I place the function `hout` in a separate file? I've tried it now but it doesn't work. Should I use some special naming?

Comment: @BartArondson I called the helper function `helper_block_func`... `hout` is not the function name, it's a local variable in that function. Yes, of course you can put it in a separate m-file, just make sure you the file is named like the function (for example "helper_block_func.m")